# Unable to boot into Linux Mint 21.2 installation media, black screen and nothing happens

Tags: boot, linux-mint, intel-graphics, intel-core-i5

My sister just built a computer with an Intel Processor i5-11400 and Intel UHD 730 graphics.

She only managed to install the latest Linux Mint 21.2 through compatibility mode because when she went into the normal one it wouldn't boot into the GUI, a black screen appears and nothing happens. Now, she can only access the Mint through Recovery mode, otherwise the black screen is there.

She also tried Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) and same thing happened, only works in Compatibility mode.

She tried nomodeset, that didn't work, also she tried going from kernel 5.15 to 5.9, nothing changed. She is now downloading kernel 6.1-oem and we'll see if that works.

Anyone got any ideas? We think it's an issue about the newest graphics, at least that's what the internet provided.

Comment: UPDATE: She removed the splash screen, apparently it was an issue with Linux asking of the drivers to load right after boot, works now. I'll post the entire solution when she gives me the link.